# Compare set of data before and after current date

Tags: php, mysql, date, comparison

I've been banging my head against the desk with something that is most likely dead simple.

The database has a collection of products from different outlets, each with expiry dates which are standard MySQL `yyyy-mm-dd` dates. I'm trying to find a way to display which outlets currently don't have any offers, vs those that do. At the moment my page looks like:

Outlets with specials:

```
Outlet 1
Outlet 3
Outlet 7
```

Outlets with no specials:

```
Outlet 2
Outlet 4
Outlet 5
```

Currently I just have a list of either

- current specials, or
- expired specials

but I'd like to display which of the outlets don't currently have any specials.

Something like:

```
SELECT outlet
FROM `specials`
WHERE `end_date` < '$today'
GROUP BY `outlet`
ORDER BY outlet ASC
WHERE outlet also doesn't have any specials after today's date
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to look at the maximum `end_date` in a `having` clause, rather than filtering in a `where` clause:

```
SELECT outlet
FROM specials
GROUP BY outlet
HAVING max(end_date) < '$today'
ORDER BY outlet ASC;
```

Note:  if you are using date comparisons to the current date, use `now()` instead of a variable set in the application.  If `$today` could really be any date, then use the variable to pass it in (although parameters are better than string substitution for passing in variables).

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks Gordon, much appreciated!